# How to keep the minibuffer in Emacs to not be cleared?

Tags: emacs, minibuffer

I sometimes need to keep the minibuffer in Emacs unchanged to see the displayed information as a reference. For example, when looking for type information of an expression in OCaml, I want at least the type is displayed in the minibuffer  (as in the below picture) until I want it to be cleared, says, by pressing some key strokes.

[image]

The problem is that for every command that I perform, even moving cursor around, the previous information displayed in the minibuffer will be immediately cleared.

Is there a way to customise the minibuffer so that it can be kept unchanged or to be cleared by pressing certain key strokes?

Comment: The information that appear in the minibuffer comes from the `*message*` buffer. So, you can do `C-h e` or `M-x view-echo-area-messages` or `left click on the minibuffer` to open it.

Comment: Thanks! That is one of the option. However, is there any way to freeze the minibuffer, or precisely, the echo area?